# Keyword or keyphrase in tagging system?

Tags: tags, keyword

In term of effectively categorizing web content, I am wondering what are the pros and cons between keyword (a.k.a tag, e.g, google-app-engine) and keyphrase (e.g. google app engine).

I know that [delicious.com](http://delicious.com/) and [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/) are using keyword as a tag. But why don't they use keyphrase instead? If they use keyword, then it may cause certain inconsistences (e.g., app-engine and appengine, web-2.0 and web2.0). I wonder if I choose using keyphrase as a tag, then it will become much better. I have no clue why those two major sites don't work as the way I thought. Are there any cons of using keyphrase? Please point it out to me.

Comment: Isn't this a question for meta.stackoverflow.com? Also, the problem you mention has be countered on Stackoverflow using a tag wiki and alias system. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info for instance.

Comment: @peSHIr: I assume the OP is designing his own tagging system, not asking how the one on Stack Overflow should work.  He's just using Stack Overflow as an example.

Comment: @RichieHindle: And I was doing the same (usnig SO as an example), trying to answer at least part of his question.

Comment: Yes, I am designing my own tagging system. My targeted users are non-technical people, so I don't expect them to find content by using dash-sperated tags, such as google-places. Thus, I am thinking if I can do 'google places', rather than 'google-places'.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious difference:

- If you use `keywords-like-this`, then a list of multiple keywords can be space-separated.
- If you allow `keyphrases like this` with spaces in, you can't space-separate the keyphrases.

That means you either introduce some other separator character that your users need to learn about, or you have a much more complex user interface for editing tags.

(The inconsistency problem you mention will happen either way: `app engine` / `appengine` vs. `app-engine` / `appengine`.)